# get the backtrace in a sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Im trying to get the backtrace in sinatra in case of an error.
I know rails has one in

`Rails.respond_to?(:backtrace_cleaner)`

and I saw that sinatra is suppose to have one (by default enabled) in `STDERR`
So i tried

`STDERR.inspect`

and I got `#<IO:<STDERR>>`

Comment: also very much worth checking out https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rescuing the exception, catch the exception object.

```
 begin
   raise "hello"
 rescue => e
   e.backtrace
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can call a method `caller` at any place and get a full backtrace as an array.